# Display One record at a time in MVC through List

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 5 records coming from a simple select stored procedure.

```
ID Name
1  RecordOne
2  RecordTwo
3  RecordThree
4  RecordFour
5. RecordFive
```

Requirement is to display one record at a time example:

Record One

Previous    Next

Two Action links or buttons with Previous and Next text.
If user clicks Next user will see

```
RecordTwo
```

and so on,same for previous case.

My model

```
namespace MVCLearning.Models

{

public class VMNews
{
    public List<Student> StudentDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
 }
```

Action

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        VMNews objnews = new VMNews();
        objnews.StudentDetails = db.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("usp_studentdetails").ToList();
        return View(objnews);
    }
```

View

```
<div>
@foreach (var item in Model.SD.Take(1))
{
    <h3>@item.Name</h3>
    <h3>@item.Age</h3>

}
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "index", new { Model.SD[0].ID})
@Html.ActionLink("Previous", "index", new { Model.SD[0].ID })
```

The way I have written the view is totally wrong am not getting how and what to write on the action and what to write on the View.

What will be one of the way to achieve this.

Comment: Your method needs to `public ActionResult Index(int? index)` or similar so that you can pass the index of the item you want to view.

Comment: And what to write in the action and what on the view.

Comment: Based on the value of `index` you will need to assign some values to view model properties (or `ViewBag`) to generate the roure values for the links. I will add an answer in 30 minutes or so. Will it only ever be 5 values, or could this be more in the future?

Comment: More records, for demo purpose I have shown 5.Am understanding the index logic and saving it to a ViewBag then passing it to a View in the ActionLink but still unclear about the syntax implementation like where to write what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you method to

```
public ActionResult Index(int? index)
{
  int max = 5; // modify based on the actual number of records

  int currentIndex = index.GetValueOrDefault();
  if (currentIndex == 0)
  {
    ViewBag.NextIndex = 1;
  }
  else if (currentIndex >= max)
  {
    currentIndex = max;
    ViewBag.PreviousIndex = currentIndex - 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ViewBag.PreviousIndex = currentIndex - 1;
    ViewBag.NextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
  }

  VMNews objnews = new VMNews();
  Student model = db.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("usp_studentdetails")
    .Skip(currentIndex).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

  return View(model);
}
```

Note that the query has been modified to return only one `Student` since that is all that you require in the view. Also I have asssumed if a user enters a value greater than the number of records it will return the last record (you may in fact want to throw an error?)

The view now needs to be

```
@model Student

<h3>@Model.Name</h3>
<h3>@Model.Age</h3>

@if (ViewBag.PreviousIndex != null)
{
  @Html.ActionLink("Previous", "Index", new { index = ViewBag.PreviousIndex })
}
@if (ViewBag.NextIndex != null)
{
  @Html.ActionLink("Next", "Index", new { index = ViewBag.NextIndex })
}
```

Comment: Refer also update for the case when the user enters a value greater than the number of records in the database. You could also add a check in case a negative value was entered.

Comment: I am going through your detailed example.Thanks for fast reply.

Comment: Hi, on the view ViewBag.PreviousIndex should be compared to what as in if condition a comparision is required thats why my code breaks on view.

Comment: Have compared it too the count of the list of records now its working.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be `@if (ViewBag.PreviousIndex != null)`

Comment: I fetched my complete list of records first so that I could use   `code var max = records.Count() - 1` I also chose to for safety set `code ViewBag.NextIndex = null`; in the second if statement in the controller.